# Usar array_search num array multidimensional php

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Em uma lista de livros dentro de um `array` multidimensional, cada `sub_array` tem uma coluna **categoria** diferente, eu gostaria de pesquisar nesse `array` por uma **categoria** por exemplo:

```
Array  "livros"
    (
        [Livro 1] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => Bleach
                [resumo] => xxx
                [categoria] => Ação, Comédia...
            )

        [Livro 2] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => Titulo livro 2
                [resumo] => xxx
                [categoria] => Ação, Psicológico, Romance ...
            )

        [livro 3] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => Titulo do livro 3
                [resumo] => xxx
                [categoria] => Romance, Vampiros ...
            )
)
```

Eu gostaria de pesquisar para exemplo quais livros se encaixam na categoria "Romance", fiz algumas pesquisas e achei o que pode ser a solução, mas por algum motivo não está funcionando, que seria essa função:

```
$romances = array_keys(array_column($livros, 'categoria'), 'Romance');
```

A função acima não traz nenhum valor, apenas um `array` vazio, o que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [**array_keys**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) com [**array_filter**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php), e na comparação com [**strpos**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) que busca a primeira ocorrência de uma texto (`string`).

**Observação:** Se quiser que não diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas troque a função de [*strpos*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) para [*stripos*](http://www.php.net/stripos) que por definição: *encontra a primeira ocorrencia de uma string sem diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas* ([site PHP stripos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php)).

<sub>Baseado na resposta do [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29098454/6797930)</sub>

```
$livros = array(
    'Livro 1' => array (
        'titulo' => 'Bleach',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'Ação, Comédia...'
    ),
    'Livro 2' => array (
        'titulo' => 'Titulo livro 2',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'Ação, Psicológico, Romance ...'
    ),
    'Livro 3' => array (
        'titulo' => 'Titulo do livro 3',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'Romance'
    )
);

$search = 'Romance';
$romances = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $livros,
        function ($value) use ($search) {
            return (strpos($value['categoria'], $search) !== false);
        }
    )
);
```

[**Exemplo Online**](http://ideone.com/1xIr1L)

***Referencias:***

- [*array_keys*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php)
- [*array_filter*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)
- [*stripos*](http://www.php.net/stripos)
- [*strpos*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Funcionou do jeito que eu preciso vlw cara

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece porque no caso da pergunta não existe nenhum livro cuja categoria é SÓ "Romance", senão retornariam dados. Temos de verificar se na string `$livros[x]['categoria']` existe a palavra "Romance", faça o seguinte:

```
$livros = array(
    'livro 1' => array(
        'titulo' => 'Bleach',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'Ação, Comédia'
    ),
    'livro 2' => array(
        'titulo' => 'Titulo livro 2',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'Ação, Psicológico, Romance...'
    ),
    'livro 3' => array(
        'titulo' => 'Titulo livro 3',
        'resumo' => 'xxx',
        'categoria' => 'romance, Vampiros ...'
    )
);
$romances = array();
foreach($livros as $livro => $data) {
    if(stripos($data['categoria'], 'Romance') !== false) {
        $romances[] = $livro; 
    }
}
print_r($romances);
```

Output de `$romances` (o array com os nomes dos livros que são também romances):

> Array ( [0] => livro 2 [[1](http://ideone.com/EPwX0W)] => livro 3 )

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/EPwX0W)

Comment: O problema é que essa função já vai ser executada, dentro de um outro foreach, pois tenho um array com as categorias e cada vez que ele passar buscar todos os livros nessa categoria, não fica pesado um foreach dentro de outro?

Comment: Dá na mesma, Leo. Poderia usar uma função nativa que daria na mesma pois é também feito uma iteração no array.

Comment: Não há nada a fazer de uma maneira ou de outra (nativamente ou não) vai ter de acontecer

Comment: Acho que com `stripos()` poderia dispensar o `strtolower()`

Comment: Testei isso aqui @DanielOmine, http://ideone.com/xmvJHL, não pode, é case sensitive

Comment: O `strpos()` é diferente de `stripos()`. Note que tem um "I" de "insensitive.

Comment: Ha tem razão, é verdade esqueci-me dessa @DanielOmine, obrigado vou editar

Comment: Vlw Pessoal funcionou muito bem, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui com isso kk

Comment: :) ainda bem que resolveu @LeoLetto. De nada