# Combinar arrays dentro de array

Tags: php, array

Alguém pode me ajudar, fazendo o favor.

Eu tenho um array nesse estilo:

```
$arrayTable = array(
   0 => array(
      'idApiUm' => 123,
      'title'  => 'Teste'
   ),
   1 => array (
      'idApiDois' => 765,
      'title'  => 'Título'
   ),
   2 => array(
      'idApiUm' => 632,
      'title'  => 'Nome'
   ),
   3 => array(
      'idApiDois' => 999,
      'title'  => 'Teste'
   ),
);
```

E preciso juntar todos arrays dentro dele que tiverem o mesmo valor em 'title', e deixar a chave desta forma:

```
0 => array(
   'idApiUm' => 123,
   'idApiDois' => 999,
   'title'   => 'Teste'
),
```

É possível? Não consigo solucionar este problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro busca as chaves que se repetem que no caso é `title`, depois os seus índices numéricos do `array` com os dados e depois junte-os com [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php), ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

$arrayTable = array(
   0 => array(
      'idApiUm' => 123,
      'title'  => 'Teste'
   ),
   1 => array (
      'idApiDois' => 765,
      'title'  => 'Título'
   ),
   2 => array(
      'idApiUm' => 632,
      'title'  => 'Nome'
   ),
   3 => array(
      'idApiDois' => 999,
      'title'  => 'Teste'
   ),
);

function get_items($array, $field)
{
    return array_unique(array_map(function($value) use ($field) { 
            return $value[$field]; 
        }, $array)
    );
}

function get_index($array, $field, $search) {
    return array_keys(
            array_filter($array,
                    function ($value) use ($search, $field) {
                        return (strpos($value[$field], $search) !== false);
                    }
            )
    );
}


$array_new = array();
foreach (get_items($arrayTable, 'title') as $value) 
{
    $array_index = get_index($arrayTable, 'title', $value);
    $array_index_item = array();
    foreach ($array_index as $i) 
    {
        if (count($array_index_item) == 0)
        {
            $array_index_item = $arrayTable[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $array_index_item = array_merge($array_index_item, $arrayTable[$i]);
        }
    }
    $array_new[] = $array_index_item;
}

var_dump($array_new);
```

<sup>[***Exemplo: IDEONE***](https://ideone.com/wqu1T8)</sup>

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [array_search](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php)
- [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)
- [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php)
- [Usar array_search num array multidimensional php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166452/54880)
- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)
- [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Eita Virgilio, muito obrigado!!!!!! Funcionou perfeitamente e de maneira dinâmica! Era exatamente o que eu estava procurando!! Não conseguia chegar à essa resposta há dias...

Comment: Se for a resposta vote nela e aceita como resposta do sua duvida @LucasMartins

Comment: Aceitei! De novo, muito obrigado Virgilio!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim...

```
<?php  $arrayTable = array(
    0 => array(
        'idApiUm' => 123,
        'title' => 'Teste'
    ),
    1 => array (
        'idApiDois' => 765,
        'title' => 'Título'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'idApiUm' => 632,
        'title' => 'Nome'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'idApiDois' => 999,
        'title' => 'Teste'
    ),
);

$result = array();

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    global $result;
    if(is_string($key))
        $result[$key] = $item;
    else
        $result[$key] += $item;
}

foreach ($arrayTable as $x)
    if($x['title'] == 'Teste')
       array_walk($x, 'test_print');
print_r($result);
?>
```

Array ( [idApiUm] => 123 [title] => Teste [idApiDois] => 999 )

Comment: Fala Carlos, tudo bem? Primeiramente, muito obrigado pela resposta!

Então, eu obtive este resultado: Array ( [idApiUm] => 632 [title] => Teste [idApiDois] => 999 )

No entanto, repare que o ID das ApiUm não está mostrando o correto, que deveria seria o 123...

Comment: MODIFIQUEI O CÓDIGO para chegar no resultado que você procura!
Incluir abaixo do foreach uma condição "if($x['title'] == 'Teste')"

Comment: Neste caso funciona perfeitamente, mas eu gostaria que esta condição fosse alcançada dinamicamente, e não apenas no caso do título "Teste"...

Comment: No seu caso é muito específico! Se fosse só recuperar o último valor de cada chave seria mais simples... Mas no caso acima você quer recuperar os valor do title 'Teste', logo precisa da validação dessa chave, senão dificilmente terei precisão no resultado.

Comment: Sim, é bem complicado! Mas acho que o Virgilio, da outra resposta, conseguiu solucionar! De qualquer jeito, muito obrigado pela ajuda Carlos!!!!